# Using bloggers robots file

Tags: blogger, spam, robots.txt, referer

My blogger blogs are getting a lot of "Referrer spam", and I'm getting sick of seeing it.
Can i use bloggers "robots.txt" file to  block these "Spammers"

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. `robots.txt` provides *hints* to the bot, regarding what pages *should* be visited and what not. However, complying with the rules is **up to the bot**. While search engines and `wget` might behave accordingly, it's really unfeasible that a spambot would ever. I mean, it would be as effective as trying to stop spam by putting a "Please, do not spam" banner in your website.

Comment: Could i write a javascript to redirect certain User-Agents Or IP Addresses

Comment: No. Again, Javascript is interpreted by the client. Bots ignore Javascript.

Comment: What about something like this http://pastebin.com/xVr7Cmyq

Comment: Nope: `gethostname()` gets the standard host name for _your_ machine. Apart from that, most spammers operate from "anonymous" IPs, not bound to any www host name. You can certainly block by IP address, instead, but: a) you need at least a contact to detect the IP address and add it to the list b) many times, spambots operate from dynamic IPs, which could be reassigned to legitimate clients or from behind NATs (and in this case, you risk blocking _a lot_ of people). Last but not least, you cannot even deploy random PHP on Blogger.

Answer (score 0):

Don't click on the links in your Stats logs. That's the only way to make referrer spam stop. read a great article by one of the Blogger forum moderator.

http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2012/04/referer-spam-cannot-be-blocked.html

Nobody is actually viewing your blog from these sites - and nobody knows about these links but you, since only you can see your Stats logs. There are no links to your blog, from these websites.

You cannot block users depending on IP (definitely not on Blogger.com )